# Line thickness in plot function in R

Tags: r, plot, xts

I wish to increase the line thickness in a plot I have created but each time I specify `lwd = 2` I receive an error referring to multiple arguments for lwd but the data still plots but there's no border, axis title or scales just the time series.

Clearly there's some other internal conflict with regards the line width but I am unsure as to what the exact cause is.

> Error in axis(1, at = xycoords$x[ep], labels = names(ep), las = 1, lwd
>   = 1,  :    formal argument "lwd" matched by multiple actual arguments

Once I remove the lwd reference the data plots as I expected but the line thickness is not what I want. How can I overcome this problem?

This is the piece of code which is causing the problem:

```
plot(x = wideRawXTS[,"DO0182U09A3"],
     xlab = "Time", 
     ylab = "RTWP Levels (dBm)", 
     main = "RTWP Vs. Time", 
     ylim = c(-110,-70), 
     major.ticks = "days", 
     minor.ticks = FALSE,
     col = "#1b9e77",
     lwd = 2)
```

Comment: The code chunk you have posted here does not contain any `lwd` argument … could you please provide the non-functional code of yours?

Comment: @goldenoslik I accidently dumped a printout from the command line while trying to troubleshoot the issue, apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example exhibiting the behaviour PigWolf is talking about

```
library(xts)

data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix)

plot(sample.xts[, "Open"], lwd=2)
```

It seems like the error appears as a result of a small bug.
If you run `plot.xts` and search for `lwd` in the returned code you'll see it pop up as a supplied argument together with `...` (ellipsis) in one of the `axis` calls. That means there will be two `lwd` arguments passed to the same function when you also specify it.

There are <s>two</s> three ways to solve this:

1. set `axes` to `FALSE` and supply axes separately.
2. modify the code by removing `lwd = 1`, an argument that probably shouldn't be there in the first place as it's completely pointless.
3. install the development version (`devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/xts")`), as mentioned by Joshua in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reproducible example!  Note that this is a bug in the version of xts on CRAN, works without error using the development version of xts.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: good to know I wasn't the first to spot this :)